# Why is the component used in the StackView not defined if it is declared in the program?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

```
TankModel { id: _model }

Connections {
    target: _model
    onModelUpdated: {
        _tankList.enabled = true;
    }
}

StackView {
    id: _stack
    anchors.fill: parent
    initialItem: _page1
}

Component {
    id: _page1

    ComboBox {
       id: _tankList
       model: _model
    }
}
```

After running the program, I get the error:
**ReferenceError: _tankList is not defined**

The error points to line number 6.

How to make `ComboBox` visible to `Connections`?
How to solve this problem?

Comment: `_tankList` is a part of a Component. You need an instance of that Component to be able to reference its contents. The StackView creates an instance, so you should try to access that. Does it work if you try `_stack.currentItem.enabled = true;`? Of course in real code, you'll need to make sure that currentItem exists and points to the right instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can instanciate your model inline. In this case the model can access its parent.

```
...
ComboBox {
   id: _tankList
   model: TankModel {
      id: _model
      
      onModelUpdated : {
         _tankList.enabled = true;
      }
   }
}
...
```

Comment: The fact is that there is another `id:_page2`, where you also need to receive data and fill in the fields.